# How to transform a generated website into a pdf

Tags: pdf, documentation

I have generated a documentation for my project - using CompoDoc.

Does anyone knows how to transform documentation into a Pdf ?

The generated documentation has the form of folder with multiples html files linking to each other.

```
.
├── classes
├── components
├── coverage.html
├── dependencies.html
├── fonts
├── graph
├── guards
├── images
├── index.html
├── injectables
├── interceptors
├── interfaces
├── js
├── miscellaneous
├── modules
├── modules.html
├── overview.html
├── pipes
├── properties.html
├── routes.html
└── styles
```